# How to write I2C Device Driver for i2c sensor?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, device-driver, i2c

I want to write i2c device driver for i2c sensor, I'm totally confusing with 
what is:

1. i2c client driver
2. what is i2c host driver
3. what is i2c adapter driver
4. what is algorithm driver
5. how char driver access i2c device information

Comment: Have you read documentation, namely http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/i2c/?

Comment: If you don't know theses things, you are not going to be able to do it, most people who have 4 year Computer engineering degrees can't do this, so you aren't going to be able to learn on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Get some information regarding for I2C [Here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface). And [This](http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices) Documentation may help you to program it.